# How to split opening hours into blocks of 30 minutes?

Tags: jquery, arrays, laravel, while-loop, fullcalendar

I'm currently working on a app to book barber appointments. I'am using fullcalendar for the appointments and i'm trying to get the business hours into seperate hours or blocks of 00:30 minutes. My database table contains a 'start' and 'end' time like 09:00 to 18:00. I was thinking about a while loop but don't now how to begin. It has to be somekind of array. Any thoughts on this?

```
Monday ['0' => '09:00',
        '1' => '09:30',
        '2' => '10:00',
       ];
Tuesday  ['0' => '09:00',
          '1' => '09:30',
          '2' => '10:00',
         ];
```

[Table structure Appointments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFRmG.jpg)
[Table structure Business_hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM3DV.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in details how this data structure will be used?

Comment: A customer can book an appointment en sees the available times. This available times is based on the opening hours of a business. so when a business is open from 09:00 to 18:00, there should be a list with available times like: 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30 till the end time 18:00 is reached. When a customer chose a time it shouldn't be on the available list anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 function get_minutes ( $start, $end ) { 

    while ( strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end) ) { 
   $minutes[] = date("H:i:s", strtotime( "$start" ) ); 
    $start = date("H:i:s", strtotime( "$start + 30 mins")) ;     
    } 
 return $minutes; 
}
```

**example**

```
$minutes = get_minutes('08:00', '10:00'); 
foreach($minutes as $minute) { 
echo $minute .'<br />'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for, it works like a charm. An addition question I also need a idea about to hide the times that booked already. I have a Appointment table the rows: start_date, end_date like  2017-06-15 13:37:00. How can I hide the times that are booked?

Comment: There is an assumption here, that the business hours in database will be always sharp hours or half of hours. If the business hours can be defined as in: 09:15 - 17:30 then this code needs to take care of this edge cases

Comment: its depend on your table structure then we can do a query .  if i can see your table structure

Comment: @Jarek.D It's only possible to add half hours of sharp hours.

Answer (score 0):

If these are time slots to be booked, you'd be better of with a data structure that represents the slots, as in:

```
Array('2017-01-01' => ('slot_id' => 'Dgf67654' ,
                       'from' => '09:00', 
                       'to' => '09:30'),
                      ('slot_id' => 'dsff7676', 
                       'from' => '09:30', 
                       'to' => '10:30'),
                       ...
)
```

and adapt the get_minutes proposed above to generate this kind of structure. This kind of data structure will be ready to use by a booking code